# Notepad++ open in same window position and size every time

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

Is there a way I can get Notepad++ to open with the same size and position every time I open it? I'm looking for similar functionality to `Sticky Window Position` in Notepad2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such customization available by default or with plugins/addons in notepad++ ..

But you can make use of windows tweeking tools like [Autosizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/), it's free!

[image]

Comment: AutoSizer uses AutoHotkey's WinWait, WinMove etc. functions, but if you're unable to do some basic scripting then I guess this is a good alternative since it presents the same options with an easy to use GUI.

Comment: @Zantier, You are welcome :)

Comment: AutoSizer only works for 32Bit applications, so you can use it for 64Bit apps.

Answer (score 3):

If your installation was with all defaults, there's a config file in your %APPDATA% folder you can check/edit to make this set correctly.

Open "%APPDATA%\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml" file in a text editor, and look for a line like this:

```
 <GUIConfig name="AppPosition" x="0" y="0" width="1024" height="900" isMaximized="no" />
```

Note that mine has the width and height settings set for a much more visible window - you'll want to adjust this relative to your typical screen layout.  I went with 1024x900 because I use this on a laptop screen AND an external screen - one has a max rez of 1600x900 and the other is 1600x1200 so I compromised.

hope that's useful to you!  Good luck!

For more detail and another fix suggestion check this link:
http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4254/

Comment: For me this is almost the correct answer. It should be %APPDATA%\Notepad++\config.xml (%APPDATA% normally points to Roaming sub-folder). My Notepad++ window was opening in a location on a (non-existent) second monitor, so I could change the AppPosition to get it back on screen

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Notepad++
2. Change the position and size of your window
3. Close Notepad++
4. Open Notepad++ again

Now all new files will be opened within the new stored window position and size.

Comment: This is how I would have expected it to work, but it does not. Documents always open the same size, and in a seemingly random location.

Comment: It does work, but only if you manually change it, if you use windows auto snap it wont save, so if you have snapped it, manually slightly adjust its size and position, then on close it will save it.

Answer (score 1):

@Ejoso's answer seems to provide the simplest solution and worked for me on the zip version. The only issue I had was trying to edit and save the `config.xml` file from within Notepad++, but closing the application afterward seemed to be resetting the file to its defaults.

So I closed all instances of Notepad++ and modified the "AppPosition" key like @Esojo described from Notepad. My edits persisted and now Notepad++ always opens to the window size and position I defined in the config.

Interestingly, the [Notepad++ manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/) warns about editing the configuration file from the application itself, but says it's possible. I tried the suggested procedure but it still didn't work for me. It's probably always just safer to edit Notepad++ files from some other editor in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Buy this 3rdparty application:

http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm

[image]

> WindowManager helps you to improve your work flow by remembering and
>   restoring the position and size of your programs and windows. Many
>   programs don't remember their position and size between sessions and
>   even Windows explorer does not always restore windows to their last
>   position. This is where WindowManager steps in and makes sure your
>   windows are placed exactly where you want them every time you open
>   them.

Comment: @Karan AutoSizer only works for 32Bit applications, that's why didn't post it.